# Notation and construction of 13th chords

Tags: chords, chord-theory

Firstly, I would like to ask whether 13th chords by default have a minor, major or diatonic 13th or is it contextual to the 3rd used.

E.g.
Am13 in the Aeolian mode:

Is the 13th F or F# (F being diatonic)

Is that different in the dorian mode? (F# being diatonic)

Secondly what is the notation for using the other 13th? Is it like (m13) or (b13)?

Comment: It may be a good idea to specify what genre you are playing/analyzing these chords in.  In the comment threads below it seems that some people are answering from a Classical perspective, where 13 chords are relatively rare.  I assumed this question is from the Jazz perspective, where you are most likely to find such a chord symbol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Minor 6th chords use the major 6 interval off the root, just like major 6ths. The minor bit is the minor 3rd.A minor 6th chord with a minor 6th interval doesn't sound good. So 13ths will use the same 6th interval, but usually an octave higher.Strictly speaking, a 13th should have 1,3,5,7,9,11 and 13 in it, but that's often impractical - on guitar, for instance, there's only 6 strings, so all couldn't be played anyway. The other problem is that the order ought to be notes in numerical order. Fine on keyboards, but that's about all.Often, a 7th (usually flat) and a sixth with the basic triad will sound fine.

I don't think chords need to be made from modes, as they already exist in the 'mother' (Ionian) key.

Comment: I don't agree.  A 13th chord does not need to have all the notes.  The notes also have no requirement to be stacked in order, in fact, that's probably the most boring way to voice such a chord.  The bit about a Minor6 chord with b6 not sounding good is entirely subjective as well.  I would express that concept by saying that adding a b6 is not functionally the same as a minor chord and would not be an appropriate substitution.

Comment: @Basstickler Theoretically chords should have all the degrees below the highest voice which is demonstrated by 'no' chords e.g. G11(no9).

Comment: That's probably why I said 'strictly'. It rarely does.There are as many ways of voicing a chord as skinning a cat. That's subjective. I tried to point out that a min6th chord doesn't have a m6 note in it.

Comment: It's way too soon to vote a 'favourite' answer. This debate may run...

Comment: From my experience and training, as well as studying on my own, I have found that there is no necessity to use all the notes.  Saying 13 does imply that the other extensions would be appropriate in the chord.  Saying 'no 9' typically means that there specifically should not be one, which would be implied without the note.

Comment: @Basstickler - personally, I've never used all the notes - on guitar ! Couldn't, and wouldn't. Mostly, I put a b7 and a maj6 on the triad, and it works for me. No-one has ever complained about it !

Comment: @Tim Answers my question. First to answer my question. Why wouldn't I accept it.

Comment: That is exactly my point.  In practice you will rarely find someone playing all of those notes.  Jazz is pretty much the place you find a 13 chord and almost no Jazz players play the 5th of a chord unless it is the result of voice leading.  I also find the #11 would be used, not natural 11, as that would change the functionality of the chord.

Comment: @TimHargreaves -  It was actual Tim that suggested you should wait to choose an answer.  I would tend to agree based on the amount of debate that has already taken place.  It is generally good to wait to choose THE answer as better ones may come along that provide more in depth information or a more understandable wording or a chart... lots of reasons to wait.  I do think that you get what you need from Tim's answer; my comments are in response to thinking it is slightly misleading as a definition.

Comment: @TimHargreaves - first past the post  doesn't make it the best answer you're going to get.

Comment: I do tend to like your answers Tim, I just get a little picky sometimes.  You are clearly knowledgeable!

Comment: I'll take that as a compliment. Ta. But I'm just about to become more knowledgeable, I hope !

Comment: Ok, so according to Mark Levine's The Jazz Piano Book, a 13 chord would be a Dominant chord and could include as little as Root, 3, 7 and 13, and 11 should always be omitted, as it would be an 'avoid note' (and as usual in a Jazz setting, the accompanist would only play the root in the absence of a bass player).  The Harvard Dictionary of Music states, in reference to 9th, 11th and 13th chords, "All such chords can be inverted, and in some circumstances, one or more pitches other than the highest may be omitted." Continued in next comment...

Comment: Though wikipedia is not the most reliable source, it seems to state that the 9 and 11 are often omitted, as well the 5.  Their example uses R, 3, 7, 13.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_chord
And this random site I just found seems to say that it is assumed that all the notes are there but that the 11 is often omitted because of its harsh dissonance but is still a 13th chord.
http://www.dolmetsch.com/musictheory17.htm#extended
So it seems that from either Classical or Jazz, the 11 is usually omitted.

Comment: Re omitted chord tones: yes "13th" does "imply" 7, 9, 11, on top of the root, 3rd and 5th Howeverthat does not mean they all have to sound. Omitting chord tones is sometimes necessary due to to voice leading considerations, or constraints of the instrument. When you do omit chord tones, omit those that least contribute to the character of the chord. For that reason, you can't omit to top note: a 13th chord with omitted 13th doesn't make sense. The 5th is a good candidate to omit since it merges almost completely with the root. 3rd is not a good candidate since it establishes mood.

Answer (score 1):

> Firstly, I would like to ask whether 13th chords by default have a
>   minor, major or diatonic 13th or is it contextual to the 3rd used.

13th Chords **always have a major 13**. When altering the 13, the extension of your chord gets smaller. The 9th and/or 11th can be omitted. But when omitting both, it's probably better written as an *add13* chord. The 3th and 5th can be omitted if they are respectively major and perfect. When omitting the 3th, but with either an 11 or 9, a sus chord is formed (11 has priority over 9). A sharp 11th is common for dominant 13 chords to avoid a clash between the 3th and 11th. The root can be omitted if it is implied by another instrument (like the bass).

*Common 13th chords:*

- C△<sup>13</sup> `C (D) (E) (F) (G) A B`
- C-<sup>13</sup> `C (D) Eb (F) (G) A Bb`
- C<sup>13</sup> `C (D) (E) (F) (G) A Bb`
- C<sup>13♯11</sup> `C (D) (E) F# (G) A Bb`
- C<sup>ø13</sup>, C-<sup>13♭5</sup> `C (D) Eb (F) Gb A Bb`
- C-<sup>△13</sup> `C (D) Eb (F) (G) A B`
- C+<sup>△13</sup>, C△<sup>13♯5</sup> `C (D) (E) (F) G# A B`
- C+<sup>13</sup> `C (D) (E) (F) G# A Bb`
- Cº<sup>△13</sup>, C-<sup>△13♭5</sup> `C (D) Eb (F) Gb A B`
- <strike>Cº<sup>13</sup></strike> `C (D) Eb (F) Gb A Bbb` -> you will never encounter this chord because B𝄫 and A clash

> Secondly what is the notation for using the other 13th? Is it like
>   (m13) or (b13)?

You would use the highest extension below the 13th of the chord, with an altered 13th.

*Examples:*

- C11<sup>♭13</sup> `C (D) (E) F (G) Ab Bb`
- C-9<sup>♭13</sup> `C D Eb (G) Ab Bb`

Comment: I think this is the best answer, because it's much clearer that the 13th is assumed to be major (A), not ♭13 (A♭).

Answer (score 0):

Most chords have a "key" feature that determines the character and musical function. For a 13th chord that's probably the diminished octave interval between the 7 and the 13. You'd also need the 3 to distinguish between major and minor. On the guitar, I'd typically play 1 7 11 13, which happens to fret pretty nicely too. So in C13 would be C Bb E A

Comment: The interval between 7 and 13 would be a Major 7, not a diminished octave.  The numbers you used to describe building this chord do not align with your example (E is 3) and I would disagree with the 11 being present.

Comment: @ Hilmar - 1,7,11,13.Would be C,B,F and A. Doesn't sound too good !  C,Bb,E and A will constitute C13, as we said before, G as 5 is not needed, and 9 and 11 can be missed out.Did you mean 1,b7,10 and 13 ?

Answer (score 0):

1. The character of the 13th is essentially determined by its third and seventh voices. In the key of C, the Aeolian mode has a b13 (F). The chord would be a min11(b13). The Dorian mode has a natural 13, so the chord would be a min13.
2. With html's superscripts, we can notate the chord and alterations appropriately.  In fact, I have created summary [harmonization tables](http://home.comcast.net/~k2a/chords.html#c-natural-minor-scale) that may answer your underlying questions.

@user10304 asserted that you can't play an actual 13th chord on guitar. While it is true that guitarists cannot simultaneously finger all of the voices as a pianist would, guitarists can still play an abbreviated version that retains the character of the 13th chord. In these tables, I have illustrated voices omitted for guitar in the color gray. The retained 13th chord voices generally include the root, third, seventh, thirteenth, together with any altered voices. Sometimes the chords get too complex for the guitar, such as in the Locrian mode.

In these tables, the highlighted chords contain "avoid" notes illustrated in red; they generally sound dissonant, so treat them accordingly.

You may readily discover these 13ths on guitar ranging from Texas blues to straight-ahead jazz. One of my favorite examples would be SRV's [Riveria Paradise](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V8wtZeVAa9I).

Answer (score -2):

You can't play an actual 13th chord on a guitar. Also a 13th chord is just the entire major scale played at the same time as one chord. You might me more interested in piano, but you can break down the chord into a guitar format by removing notes.

Comment: We CAN actually play 13th chords on guitar.  For example, we can play Cmaj13 (C - E - A - B - E), Dm13 (D - B - C - F), Em7 (b13) (E - C - D - G - B), Fmaj13 (F - A - E - A - D - E), G13 (G - B - F - G - B - E), Am7 (b13) (A - F - G - C - E), and Bm7 (b13) (B - G - A - D).

Comment: You can not unless you tune weird and use 7 strings. You need 7 notes for an actual 13th sort of chord. When you omit notes leading up to it such as the 2 or 4.. you are not playing a real 13th sort of chord.

Comment: I wouldn't accept a chord name for a chord that isn't containing the required notes of the chord. That would mean there is no system and music theory is not a science or shouldn't exist at all.